# Can an Android Studio submodule depend on classes from the application.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Basically I have an application and I'm making a submodule to publish to a different set of devices.

I'd like to reuse classes from the main application in the submodule.

If I try to add the main application as a dependency in the module I get this error:

> Warning:Dependency [Project Name]:app:unspecified on project resolves to an APK >archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency.

If I remove the dependency I can't access the classes from the main application.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you looked into gradle build variants? https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: That makes sense and will probably work. It seems strange though, that when you set up a build to have a hardware option, Android Studio builds a submodule.